# How to restrict who can invite users with devise_invitable and cancancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan, devise-invitable

I'm using devise_invitable for inviting users, and cancancan for defining abilities in the app. How do I define the ability for who can send invites?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the method `authenticate_inviter!` in your `ApplicationController`

```rb
def authenticate_inviter!
  send(:"authenticate_#{resource_name}!", force: true).tap do |inviter|
    @current_ability = ::Ability.new(inviter)
    authorize! :invite, SysManager
  end
end
```

and then use cancancan to define who `can :invite, SysManager`

Comment: Works for me without `@current_ability = ::Ability.new(inviter)`

Answer (score 0):

```
# app/controllers/invitations_controller.rb
class Devise::InvitationsController < DeviseController
    ...
    before_action :is_admin?, :only => [:new, :create]
    ...

private

    def is_admin?
      current_user.role == 'admin'
    end
end
```